# Set of conditionally summable sequences is Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, borel-sets

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the space of real-valued sequences with it natural topology and the corresponding Borel $\sigma $-algebra. I want to see if the subset $S:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: \sum_{n\geqslant 1}x_n\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is Borel. As far as I can see, using the metric

$$
d(x,y):=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n (1+|x_n-y_n|)}
$$

the set $S$ is neither open nor closed. But I don't have a clue about how I can continue from there. Can someone give me an answer or a reference related to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the statement is true. To see this observe that the map $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto \{x_n\}_{n\leqslant m}$ is trivially measurable for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$ as the topology in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the product topology and so in this case the Borel $\sigma $-algebra coincides with the $\sigma $-algebra generated by the cylinders (because $\mathbb{N}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable).

So let $f_m:\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}^m,\, x\mapsto (x_1,\ldots ,x_m)$, now as $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a topological vector space we have that the map $s_m:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R},\, (x_1,\ldots ,x_m)\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^m x_k$ is continuous, therefore the functions defined by $h_m:=s_m\circ f_m$ are measurable for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, from basic results of measure theory, we knows that the functions defined by
$$
ls:\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}},\, x\mapsto \limsup_{m\to\infty}h_m(x)\\
li:\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}},\, x\mapsto \liminf_{m\to\infty}h_m(x)
$$

are also measurable. Now the set in question is just the set defined by
$$
\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: ls(x)=li(x) \,\land\, ls(x)\in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
and so it is measurable.∎

Comment: +1, nice. I must ask, it never came up in my measure theory studies that one must be careful with “$\Bbb N$ countable and $\Bbb R$ second countable”. I’ve always treated the Borel sigma algebra on a product space as generated by the (open) (measurable) cylinders, since the cylinders are precisely the generators of the topology and so are precisely the generators of the sigma algebra. Why should we worry about countability?

Comment: @FShrike because in a general setting $A^{T}$, for some index set $T$, and the product topology in it, then the Borel $\sigma $-algebra could be be bigger than the $\sigma $-algebra generated by the cylinders. In any case we have that $\sigma (C)\subset \mathcal{B}(A^T)$, where $\sigma (C)$ is the $\sigma $-algebra generated by the cylinders and $\mathcal{B}(A^T)$ the Borel $\sigma $-algebra. When $T$ is countable and $A$ is second countable it is the case that both $\sigma $-algebras coincides. Continue...

Comment: But its true that, in any case, the map $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto \{x_n\}_{n\leqslant m}$ would be measurable, so we dont need to care about the possible differences in the $\sigma $-algebras, anyway I added the line stating it identity to clarify myself when writing my reasoning.

Comment: Ah... I think I overlooked that the $\sigma$-generation will only use countably many unions at most, whereas the topology generation will use arbitrarily large unions. That's why the countable-second countable point matters, right?

Comment: @FShrike yes, that's it